# Type not found error when call isn't inside a function

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to figure out why this error is ocurring, but I have had no success.

When I try to compile this code

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

class MyRand
{
    gmp_randclass randGen(gmp_randinit_default);
};


int main()
{
    MyRand s();
    gmp_randclass gmpRand(gmp_randinit_default);

    return 0;
}
```

using this command `g++ Random.cpp  -lgmpxx -lgmp`, I get the follow message:

> In file included from Random.cpp:3:0: Random.cpp:8:27: error:
>   ‘__gmp_randinit_default’ is not a type
>        gmp_randclass randGen(gmp_randinit_default);

But, note, this line

```
gmp_randclass randGen(gmp_randinit_default);
```

is the same of this one (inside the main function)

```
gmp_randclass gmpRand(gmp_randinit_default);
```

and only the first generate an error.

Also, if I define the class MyRand as follow (initializing the mpz_randclass inside a function)

```
class MyRand
{
    void func()
    { 
         gmp_randclass randGen(gmp_randinit_default);
    }
};
```

I can compile it with no erros.

Does someone know what is going on?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Btw, this: `MyRand s();` doesn't create a local variable, it declares a function.

Comment: I didn't understand... It creates a local variable s and run its constructor, no?

Comment: No, it declares a function called `s` that takes no arguments and returns a `MyRand`. Google "most vexing parse".

Comment: @SebastianRedl, I searched it... But can I declare a function inside another function? Because this line is inside the `main`.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can't define it, but you can declare it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not initialize class members where they are defined (at least not before C++11). You may put it in constructor.

```
class MyRand
{
public:
    MyRand() : randGen(gmp_randinit_default) {
    }
private:
    gmp_randclass randGen;
};
```

Comment: It worked! But, what is the difference between your construtor and this one  `MyRand(){
       randGen(gmp_randinit_default);
     }`
 ? Because this one doesn't work

Comment: Ok, I did my job and found out that it's called *initialisation list*. But the texts I read says that it is used to initialize `const` and `reference` fields. Isn't This the case here, ritght? I mean, randGen is neither a `const` nor a `reference`.

Comment: In fact, when I try to use the constructor that I wrote in the first comment above, I received this error: *matching function for call to gmp_randclass::gmp_randclass()*. So, I think the `gmp_randclass` has no default constructor. But I don't understand why this default constructor is called.

Comment: you can initialize any member in `initialization list`, not only `const` and `reference`. I don't know where you read this.

Comment: `MyRand(){ randGen(gmp_randinit_default); }` this code acutally doesn't make any sense. 1. before entering the body of MyRand(), randGen should be properly initialized. since you don't initialize it in `initialization list`. it will be constructed with default constructor which it doesn't have. it' why you received that error. 2. you can not initialize randGen in the function body of MyRand's constructor. it' already constructed! you may assign a value to it. but it will never be constructed twice!

Comment: I got it, all the class fields are initialized before the execution of the constructor.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a {} brace initializer or an = initializer

```
class MyRand
{
    gmp_randclass randGen{gmp_randinit_default};
};
```

And then Try compiling with c++11 support

```
g++ -std=c++11 Random.cpp  -lgmpxx -lgmp
```